# Android debug / release version of application

Tags: android, debugging, release-mode

I have one question about finding if your application is in release mode or in debug.
I need to find a way to detect the applications mode automatically with a function. For now I'm using a simple way declaring a `boolean` which everytime I have to change `true/false`. But sometimes me, or the other developer may forget to change it. Actually I need this because, I'm using an error handler in my app which is sending to our server exceptions which are uncaught. And I don't want to do this in debug mode.

So is there any way I can detect this with some functions which my app will do automatically, without using any variables like I do?

Comment: I don't think you can do this simply.  You can try retrieving `android:debuggable` attribute of your application from the manifest, but that, again, isn't a 100% certainty.

Comment: The other alternative would be to retrieve the hash of the signature from the apk and compare it with a known debug/release signatures used to sign your app.

Comment: So I'll have to stick with the boolean variable

Answer (score 1):

There is no general solution but you may use [isDebuggerConnected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#isDebuggerConnected%28%29).

BUT this solution would also trigger/show the debug features if your users connect their phones to the PC and uses ddms themselves.

Maybe you sould combine this with one of the checks Aleks G suggested, and popup a Toast-message on every start that reminds you to disable debug ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this?

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    // what shall happen in debug version
} else {
    // release version
}
```